# Making a cross-platform PyPI package with C++ extensions (wrapped with pybind11, built with bazel)

Tags: pip, bazel, pypi, pybind11

I have a hybrid C++/Python project. It uses [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to wrap C++ code for Python and [bazel](https://bazel.build/) to build the solution. I'm quite happy with this technology stack. Upon installing a C++ compiler, a Python distribution and bazel, a single `bazel run` command can download dependencies, build and run the entire C++/absl/Python/numpy conglomerate.

But in order to make things even simpler for the users I would like to package my code as a PyPI package, so that it can be downloaded with `pip install`. I want the package to be cross-platform and run on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

What is the clearest way to set up a pipeline that builds, packages and uploads everything to PyPI when a new release is produced?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Please, could you share what was your solution to this question? Thank you!

Comment: @NycholasMaia, unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. One thing I could say is that from what I've heard PyPI is not well-suited for cross-language packages, and achieving it with Conda would be easier (if you are ok with that). But I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer, but I have successfully used it in [this library](https://github.com/patrickfletcher/clODE), inspired by [grpc's approach](https://github.com/grpc/grpc). The trick is to invoke bazel through bazelisk.py with setup.py, copy the bazel output file(s), and then packaging Python with a pyproject.toml file.

Steps (assuming that your bazel code already builds):

1. Add a setup.py that can invoke bazelisk.py and copy the binary to the right output directory (see [1](https://github.com/patrickfletcher/clODE), [2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc)).
2. Add other Python files in pyproject.toml. Add any non-Python files in MANIFEST.in, so python can include them (see [1](https://github.com/patrickfletcher/clODE)).
3. Create a venv with your package and run tests in the venv*.
4. Setup github actions that install the package, build binaries and run tests in the venv. I use a Makefile for this in [1](https://github.com/patrickfletcher/clODE).
5. Using GitHub's runners (see the `.github/workflows/*.yml` files in [1](https://github.com/patrickfletcher/clODE)), build C++ binaries for all your target platforms, so users don't have to. You can upload these to pip. Use matrix builds to cover every version of Python you target. You can also upload an sdist build for anyone who wants to build the code themselves.

*This step could be improved.